# Map tiles, GDAL/gdal2tiles, trying to find where our bottleneck is

Tags: gdal, gdal2tiles

I'm new to map tiling and the somewhat extensive testing I've been benchmarking, I've either hit a floor (unlikely imo) or I'm doing something extremely wrong. Server specs are 3.7 ghz/8 threads, 16GB ram, SSD. Also tested on same cpu, 32GB ram, with an NVMe thinking there may have been a disk/memory bottleneck.

Through our testing, we're trying to generate zoom levels 5-10 only and it's taking roughly ~40 seconds for the gdal2tiles generation. It seems almost counter-intuitive but running gdal2tiles on 4 threads is only ~5-8 seconds slower than if it was run on 8 threads. So we're trying to find out where the bottleneck, or if we are somehow hitting a floor of just how fast we can process the below image. I have a hard time believing we're hitting a floor as there are many tile providers doing what we are doing up to zoom levels 19 even but, again being new to map tiling, outside of hardware I can't seem to understand where our below workflow (speed) can be improved.

I have a PNG, 14000x10800 and my workflow is currently

`gdal_translate -co "TILED=YES" -of Gtiff -a_ullr -128 58 -65 20 -a_srs EPSG:4326 [in-png] [out-tiff]`

and then

`gdalwarp -wm 2048 -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -ts 14000 10800 [in-tiff] [out-reprojected-tiff]`

and finally

`/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py -s EPSG:3857 --processes=8 -r near -p \"mercator\" -z 5-10 [in-reprojected-tiff] [out-tile-dir]`

If I do zoom 5-9 the ~40s goes to ~10s, so I'm wondering if there is some sort of interpolation happening on the tile generation (due to the image size) and whether or not there is some sort of way to not have the interpolation happen - if *that* is the issue.

This is all being run on the latest GDAL 3.5, so there is no old versions of parallel gdal2tiles that would make a difference nowadays.

Comment: There are 4 times more tiles on zoom level 10 than on level 9 and considerably longer execution time is expected. Tiled input file should give some speed-up. Try this as a second command  `gdalwarp -wm 2048 -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -ts 14000 10800 -co TILED=YES [in-tiff] [out-reprojected-tiff]`

Comment: I'm honestly at my wits end, I've tried TILED=YES on both translate, and warp, nothing seem to make a difference. I'm not saying it's to be expected per se, but I feel like *something* has to be wrong with either the original source (although translate takes ~2 seconds), the translate'd tiff (warp takes ~3.5s) or something else.

It literally seems like no amount of hardware actually changes the processing time of tiling, but I refuse to believe we're at the floor, again, because there are weather radar providers that do zoom to 15+ and I know we'd easily be at 30+ minutes if we tried that.

Comment: I've tried running each zoom level on it's own iteration as well - no real difference per se, but again we can generate 5-9, with -r near (as it's the fastest) in ~10s, 5-8 is ~3.5s. And I do admit, 35s for 5-10 isn't huge to most people, but when you're doing it for 72 "hours" of tiles (again, weather radar)... it's a huge deal.

Comment: If you calculate the ratio tiles/second at each zoom level, does the process go slower when the zoom level is increasing?

Comment: Unless I’m misunderstanding, do you simply mean how long zoom 5 takes, 6 takes, 7 takes, etc?

Comment: Not really. Each higher zoom level has 4 times more tiles than the previous one https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels. Chech how many 256x256 tiles you have in your [out-tile-dir] at each zoom level and count the **ratio** `time it tool to create the tiles at zoom level / tile count at zoom level`.

Comment: Ahh, yes, it does increase the further zoom you go in. But that would be assumed as well, no?